# Deleting the neighbouring elements of an array

Tags: java, arrays

Suppose, I have an array A. I need to delete the all the ith elements only if the ith element has both the neighboring elements i.e (i-1)th and (i+1)th and also shrink the size of the array as and when that element is found. Also, if any such element satisfies this condition, calculating its cost as well each time, according to the formula :

cost = (A[i]*A[i-1]) + (A[i]*A[i+1]) + (A[i-1]*A[i+1]) ;
Example:

A = {1,2,3,4}

After deleting element '2':
A = {1,3,4}

After deleting element '3':
A = {1,4}

I don't know how to use ArrayList. Could someone guide me so as to complete this task by just using the array concept as I am unable to move forward with this problem?

PS: Not a homework

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;


 class TestClass
{
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception
{

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int T = sc.nextInt();
    int cost=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < T; i++)   // scanning no. of test cases
     {
       int N = sc.nextInt();  // scanning no. of elements
        int[] A = new int[N];
        for(int j=0 ; j<N ; j++)
        {
          A[j] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        while (A.length>2)
        {
              cost = cost + getResultForLocation(A, 1);
              A = reduceArray(A, 1);
          }
    }

    System.out.println(cost);
}

static int getResultForLocation(int[] array, int location)
{
int sum = 0;

sum = sum + (array[location] * array[location - 1]) + (array[location] * array[location + 1]) + (array[location - 1] * array[location + 1]);

    return sum;
}


static int[] reduceArray (int[] array, int locationToRemove)
 {
if (array==null || array.length<=2)
 {
  return array;
}
if (locationToRemove == array.length || locationToRemove==1)
 {
  return array;
}
int[] returnArray = new int[array.length-1];
for (int i=0;i<locationToRemove;i++)
{
  returnArray[i]=array[i];
}
for (int i=locationToRemove;i<array.length-1;i++)
 {
  returnArray[i]=array[i+1];
}
return returnArray;
}


 }
```

Comment: Arrays in java cannot be "shrunk". An array created with 4 elements will always have 4 elements. ArrayList combines the concept of array and the concept of "size in use". It's likely exactly what you need. Please invest some time in learning about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at these methods (working from your code):

```
import java.util.*;


 class TestClass
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numberOfTests = sc.nextInt();
    int cost = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTests; i++) // scanning no. of test cases
    {
      int arraySize = sc.nextInt(); // scanning no. of elements
      int[] array = new int[arraySize];
      for (int j = 0; j < arraySize; j++) {
        array[j] = sc.nextInt();
      }

      while (array.length > 2) {
        cost = cost + getResultForLocation(array, 1);
        array = reduceArray(array, 1);
      }
    }

    System.out.println(cost);
  }

  static int getResultForLocation(int[] array, int location) {

    int cost = 0;
    if (location > 0 && location < array.length - 1) {
      // logic part
      cost = cost + (array[location] * array[location - 1]) + (array[location] * array[location + 1]) + (array[location - 1] * array[location + 1]);
    }
    return cost;
  }

  static int[] reduceArray(int[] array, int locationToRemove) {

    if (array == null || array.length <= 2) {
      return array;
    }
    if (locationToRemove == array.length) {
      return array;
    }
    int[] returnArray = new int[array.length - 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < locationToRemove; i++) {
      returnArray[i] = array[i];
    }
    for (int i = locationToRemove; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
      returnArray[i] = array[i + 1];
    }
    return returnArray;
```

}

The method **getResultForLocation** calculates the cost for the element in position x, if it's a legal location, and returns it.

The method **reduceArray** deletes the element in position x and returns a smaller array.

In the main part I built one accumulation possibility - start with the first eligible location, calculate cost, remove item - and repeat until the array is reduced to two members, accumulating the cost at each step. The result for the array presented here is 30.

In the console enter the numbers:
1
4
1
2
3
4

And the result is
30

Comment: Your solution compiled and executed perfectly!! Thanks a lot!! Except this : I am not getting the correct cost according to the formula mentioned in the question. For the example provided in the question , the answer should come as 30 but it's displaying 37. Also,I have edited the code in the question according to your code.Could you please point out the mistake?

Comment: You're right. I fixed something in the example to the code, and added a main method to show how I think this should be executed. Can you see that the result is as you expect? If so, I'd appreciate if you could accept my answer.

Comment: I did exactly what you suggested. But now, it's not even showing the output after taking all the inputs from the user. It's just displaying a blinking cursor. What might be the cause?Please suggest the changes. Oh, and yes, that's a sure thing that I'll upvote your answer.I have edited the code in the question as per your edits.

Comment: I see you updated the code in the question to reflect some of the changes. You should remove the "|| locationToRemove==1" from reduceArray (that was a mistake) and you should also use reduceArray outside of getResultForLocation - it has to change the array and return it for the next iteration. To make it easier, I simply changed me example to reflect your full code (with the scanner).

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Now, it's working fine as per the requirements and producing the correct o/p.

Comment: I tried upvoting your answer but it seems as if I'm not eligible to upvote it as of now. It's displaying the notification: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputations are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed score". I'll surely upvote it as soon as I escalate from my current reputation.

Comment: You can still accept the answer - it's marking a green tick next to it, not related to upvoting. Any poster of a question can accept an answer, regardless of reputation points.

Comment: At least let's use `Arrays.copyOf` if you must do it thins way.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use an Arraylist? In that case [try this one](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-arraylist). That one explains pretty well how an Arraylist work.